# React Router Link not rendering as clickable button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Not really sure I'm doing wrong here. I have a header component which I am then using in my main app component where my "page" components are conditionally rendered based on the app. Manually going to the routes works, however React Router's Link component is not rendering the links as clickable buttons thus I can't click on anything...

Here is my header component:

```
function Header(props) {

    const links = props.links.map(link => {
        return (

            <Link to={{pathname: link.path}} key={link.title}>{link.title}</Link>

        );
    });

    return(
        <Navbar className="border-bottom" bg="transparent" expand="lg">
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Garrett Love</Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle className="border-0" aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="ml-auto">
                    {links}
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );

}
```

I did try setting the `to` prop as both `to={link.path}` and `to="/about"` but neither worked.

I'm just putting this component in my main app component like so:

```
render() {
    return(
        <Router>
            <Container className="p-0" fluid={true}>
                <Header links={this.state.headerLinks} />
                <Route path="/" exact render={() => <Home title={this.state.home.title} subTitle={this.state.home.subTitle} />} />
                <Route path="/about" render={() => <About title={this.state.about.title} />} />
                <Footer />
            </Container>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

Comment: _Link component is not rendering the links as clickable buttons_... Maybe `this.state.headerLinks` is empty?

Answer (score 0):

I see you has header component and some app component
But in your app component you show `<Gbar />` and dont show `<Header />`
The best way to fix this:

In `Header`

```
const Header = props => 
    <Navbar className="border-bottom" bg="transparent" expand="lg">
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Garrett Love</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle className="border-0" aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="ml-auto">
              {props.links.map(link => <Link to={link.path} key={link.title}>{link.title}</Link>)}
            </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
```

And in `App`:

```
render() {
  return(
      <Router>
          <Container className="p-0" fluid={true}>
              <Header links={this.state.headerLinks} />
              <Route path="/" exact render={() => <Home title={this.state.home.title} subTitle={this.state.home.subTitle} />} />
              <Route path="/about" render={() => <About title={this.state.about.title} />} />
              <Footer />
          </Container>
      </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry I must have overlooked that. It’s called Gbar, I meant to change it to Header for the sake of the question but they’re are properly named in my project